# Mod Rewrite - Advanced issue

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, subdomain, wildcard-subdomain

I am needing to translate an unknown subdomain to a variable so the following would apply:

- `http://test.example.com/` → `http://www.example.com/?domain=test`
- `http://xyz.example.com/` → `http://www.example.com/?domain=xyz`
- `http://www.example.com/` → `http://www.example.com/`
- `http://www.example.com/pageA/` → `http://www.example.com/pageA/`
- `http://fish.example.com/pageB?somevar=something` → `http://www.example.com/pageB?somevar=something&domain=fish`
- `http://www.example.com/pageB?somevar=something` → `http://www.example.com/pageB?somevar=something`
- `http://fish.example.com/pageB` → `http://www.example.com/pageB?domain=fish`

As you can see all I need to do is replace any subdomain with `www` and append the subdomain name as a get var called *domain*.

I'm getting really lost with this.

Edit: Oh I also want the user to still see the subdomain in the url, rather than redirecting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([a-z]+)\.example\.com$
RewriteCond %1 !=www
RewriteRule ^ http://www.example.com%{REQUEST_URI}?domain=%1 [QSA]
```

Comment: Will this preserve other get vars? e.g. ?var=test&domain=xx

Comment: @DwayneBull: Yes, the *QSA* flag will automatically append the original requested query to the new one.

Comment: I added [P,QSA] and changed the first line to: RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.example\.com$  then it worked perfect. Thanks.

Comment: @DwayneBull: Oh, it should have looked like it looks now.

Answer (score 0):

I would use:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !=www.example.com
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.|)(.+)\.example\.com$
RewriteRule ^.*$ http://www.example.com/$1?domain=%2 [QSA]
```

This will also rewrite `www.fish.example.com` to `...?domain=fish`.